# Query eloquent relationship with more than one column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Playing around with laravel's eloquent relationships.
I have these relationships.

Order:

```
id
id_customer
```

Order.php

```
public function orderDetails(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\OrderDetail', 'order_id');
}
```

OrderDetail

```
id
order_id
product_id
quantity
```

OrderDetail Model

```
 public function product()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'id', 'id');
}

public function order(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Order', 'order_id', 'id');
}
```

Product

`id
  name
  price`

When dd'ed
    dd($this->order->with('orderDetails')->get();

I am able to get the order and orderdetails with the the product's id included in the order details. But I want to be able to get the name of the product so I can display it.

What query do I run or better way to define my relationships?

Comment: there is no name, i dont see a name column??!!

Comment: product has a name column

Comment: Just edited it to show properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$this->order->with('orderDetails', 'orderDetails.product')->get();
```

Relation should be `belongsTo()`, but not `hasMany()`:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

Also, you could use many-to-many relationship here. But only if it's suitable.

Comment: I tried this and the orderDetails comes as an empty array.

Comment: Did you change relation? Does `$this->order->with('orderDetails', 'orderDetails.product')->get();` work for you?

Comment: `$this->order->with('orderDetails')->get();` actually gives me the details which includes the id of the product. But I don't know how to get the name of the product

Comment: If you'll use `with('orderDetails')` and you'll try to get name of the product, you'll meet [N+1 query problem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: @BernardParah thanks for the feedback, I've edited code in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

just for everyone who visit this question as a reference, as you have asked for relationship suggestion, here is a way i might achieve this and my opinion.

its actually products belongs to many orders and orders belongs to many products. i see that order detail is a pivot. you can create a model for that too if you want.

`products` table

```
id
customer_id
```

Product.php

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class, 'order_details', 'order_id', 'product_id')->withPivot('quantity');
}
```

`orders` table

```
id
name
price
```

Order.php

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'order_details', 'product_id', 'order_id')->withPivot('quantity');
}
```

i might not create a `OrderDetail` as there is no solid reference to the table.
just the `order_details` table

```
id
order_id
product_id
quantity
```

but if i were to create OrderDetail model here is how it would be

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'product_id');
}

public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'order_id');
}
```